# standalone client to hear on graphql subscriptions without a GUI

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to write a standalone client that hears after subscribing to the exposed graphql subscription on an apollo server.
But I can only find the ones which requires a browser to trigger it.

I want the listening on the opened websocket to be automated. 
I have taken a look at https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws, but it didn't work through.

Feeling lost here. Would be glad if someone can point in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a great tool for the same https://github.com/hasura/graphqurl
Adding it here so it could help other folks looking for the same.